# Dictionary.ContainsKey return false even thought the key exists

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have piece of code as below:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
        { "de-DE", "German"},
        { "en‐GB", "English"},
        { "en‐US", "English"},
        { "es‐ES", "Spanish"},
        { "es‐MX", "Spanish"},
        { "fr‐CA", "French"},
        { "fr‐FR", "French"},
        { "hu‐HU", "Hungarian"},
        { "pl‐PL", "Polish"},
        { "pt‐PT", "Portuguese"},
        { "nl‐NL", "Dutch"},
        { "nb‐NO", "Norwegian"},
        { "sv‐SE", "Swedish"},
        { "it‐IT", "Italian"},
};
bool check = dictionary.ContainsKey("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(check);
```

The **`check` returns `false`**.
Could someone help to explain it?

Comment: The key you're inserting has one type of dash, the check you're running a different one.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich is right. Just find `-` in this page!

Comment: That's correct, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed already *Your dashes aren't the same*. I have added another item to your `Dictionary` that gives you the expected result and compare the underlying [IL](https://www.dotnetperls.com/il), by [`Ildasm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) to know the difference:

```
{ "en‐US", "English"},
{ "en-US", "English2"},
```

And:

```
IL_002d:  nop
IL_002e:  dup
IL_002f:  ldstr      bytearray (65 00 6E 00 10 20 55 00 53 00 )                   // e.n.. U.S.
IL_0034:  ldstr      "English"
IL_0039:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::Add(!0,
                                                                                                                 !1)
IL_003e:  nop
IL_003f:  dup
IL_0040:  ldstr      "en-US"
IL_0045:  ldstr      "English2"
IL_004a:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::Add(!0,
                                                                                                                 !1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your dashes aren't the same. Take a look at what your text looks like in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.1.html) (useful when you need to debug character related stuff like this):

After replacing your dash with an actual `-`, [the code works as expected](http://csharppad.com/gist/508cbfa67fe684db6bec912d3e44c771).

[image]

**EDIT**

Thanks, @Scott Chamberlain for the .[net fiddle that highlights the character differences](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwZYCn).

Comment: Here is [a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwZYCn) that compares the two versions (Was going to use it in my own answer but yours is plenty good)

Comment: Thanks, @ScottChamberlain, that fiddle is very helpful. I added it to the answer.